# JSON to Google Charts using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated!
I am trying to construct google charts using a ajax response form PHP file. Following is my gettabledata.php file and the output of it:

```
 $data= array(
             'cols' => array(
                          array('id' => 'Area','label' => 'Area', 'type' => 'string'),
                          array('id' => 'Condition','label' => 'Condition', 'type' => 'string')),
          'rows' => array());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($data['rows'], array('c' => array(
  array('v' => $row['Area']),
  array('v' => $row['Condition']))));
  } 

$jsonData = json_encode($data);  
echo $jsonData;
```

The output is:

```
   {"cols":[{"id":"Area","label":"Area","type":"string"}, {"id":"Condition","label":"Condition","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Sk"},{"v":"Healthy"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Sk"},{"v":"Healthy"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Sk"},{"v":"Healthy"}]}]}
```

When I used the following code to construct the graph I get the error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: $jsonTableData is not defined**

This is my php file:

```
 function drawItems(num) {
    //alert(num);
  var jsonTableData = $.ajax({
  url: "gettabledata.php",
  data: "q="+num,
  dataType:"json",
  async: false
}).responseText;
var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable($jsonTableData);
var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(tabledata);
}
```

Comment: That is because `$jsonTableData` is not defined in this case - `jsonTableData` is.

Comment: Hint - `var jsonTableData = $.ajax({`

Comment: @Buggabill, so, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after hours and hours Google searching this, I found the solution :)

**Here is the answer:**

```
function drawItems(num) {
  var jsonTableData = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
  url: "gettabledata.php",
  data: "q="+num,
  dataType:"json",
  async: false
}).responseText);


var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTableData);
var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(tabledata);
```

}